# Determine if a websocket send() is finished

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is there a way to get notified if a certain `send()` has finished? As i noticed the `send()` function is not blocking and the code continuous. Is there a simple way to either make it blocking or getting somehow notified if the send is finished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could rely on Socket.bufferedamount (never tried)

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/network.html#dom-websocket-bufferedamount

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://game.example.com:12010/updates');
socket.onopen = function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (socket.bufferedAmount == 0){
          // Im' not busy anymore - set a flag or something like that
        }
    }, 50);
};
```

Or implement an acknowledge answer from the server for every client message (tried, works fine)

Comment: I feared that. Thanks for the hint on bufferedamount – but i think i have to totally handle this on the server side which i wanted to avoid. the acknowledgement message is a good idea, but in that case i can handle the hole process serverside in my kind of situation. i let this question unanswered for a bit – maybe some one else has an idea but i will mark it as answered by you shorty, thanks.